# Storing separated strings

Tags: c, string, stdio, words

So I'm trying to write this program that takes a string, seperates the strings into words and puts the seperated words into a format like "word1+word2+word3..." 
I've written a C program that gets a string and seperates the string into words. But I'm a little confused on how to keep each individual word and then place it in the above format.

Here is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
 int wordCount = 0;
 char realString[200];
 char testString[200];
 char * nextWordPtr;

 printf("Input string\n");
 gets(realString);


 strcpy(testString,realString);

 nextWordPtr = strtok(testString," "); // split using space as divider

 while (nextWordPtr != NULL) {

 printf("word%d %s\n",wordCount,nextWordPtr);

 wordCount++;

 nextWordPtr = strtok(NULL," ");
}

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand really what you want? if you just want to output the string like this : '*word0+word1+...etc*', you can use this code to accomplish this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INPUT_STRING_LEN                128

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char input_string[INPUT_STRING_LEN];
        char *out_string;
        int index;

        /* Get user input */
        fgets(input_string, INPUT_STRING_LEN, stdin);

        out_string = (char *) malloc((INPUT_STRING_LEN + 1) * sizeof(char));
        /* Loop through input string and replace space with '+' */
        index = 0;
        while (input_string[index] != '\0')
        {
                if (input_string[index] == ' ')
                        out_string[index] = '+';
                else
                        out_string[index] = input_string[index];

                index++;
        }

        /* We got this out string */
        fprintf(stdout, "We got this out string :\n--->\n%s<---\n", out_string);

        /* Free the allocated memory */
        free(out_string);

        return 0;
}
```

If you want something else please edit the question.

Comment: `while (input_string[index] != EOF)` seems like a bad advice. Maybe you intended to test against '\0' ?